# is there a command that automatically downloads files from server?

Tags: cron

I am using crontab along with mysqldump command to take my db backups once in 2 days.I need to download these files from the server to my pc..can i automate this download process too using some command??Please help me..Thanks in advance..

My pc is not using linux..

Comment: Are we to assume both ends are Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `crontab` I assume we are talking about Linux-to-Linux boxes, then `scp` is what will work the best doing exactly what you want.

All you need to do is,

- Figure out **the commands** to be run at every nth interval.

  e.g. `#scp user@hostname:/path-to-srcfile/filename /destination-path/new-filename`
- Couple them in a neat **shell file** with **logging enabled** (directing the response messages/error to a log file)
- **Schedule** it using crontab/at or your preferred scheduling tool

and you are done :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that your PC is not linux, most of the advice given already will work, BUT ONLY if you create a share on your Windows box and mount that share on your server. Windows shares can be mounted with the CIFS type, like this

```
mount -t cifs //server/share /mountpoint credentials=filename
```

You will need to use the correct credentials, i.e. either a local user account or an AD user account on the PC. IF you use this on a regular basis, it's probably best to put the credentials in a small separate file.

Read more in the man pages for mount.cifs

Once you have mounted the share, follow the advice from Mohit Nanda to complete the job.

Answer (score 0):

scp? rsync?

Answer (score 0):

If both are linux boxes, you can have your ssh-key exchanged(but review security once) and thenembed scp+mysqldump in a small script and put the same in crontab in place currently existing single mysqldump.

Hope it helps..

Best Regards
Debajit Kataki